# Click event of tree view in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I created a tree View in OpenERP . It's without 'editable' property , and contains some many2one fields.

How to make it open the related object's form view , when I click the many2one fields?

For example, there is a 'sale order' field in this tree view. When I click this column, it  open the sale order's form view, as I click the same field in form View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you See on OpenERP 6.1 and trunk this Thing implmentated on all relation Field, I have attached a Screen Shot of the OpenERP 6.1 and trunk which shows the  Relation field as URL which Re-direct you on to the from view of that relational record.

- OpenERP 6.1 Sales Order Form view, Whre you can See Partner and Address  m2o as URL.[image: OpenERP 6.1 Sales Forom View]
- OpenERO Trunk Opportuniyt Form view yu can see the relation fields Partenr and Sales Personas URL:[image: OpenERP Trunk]

Thank You

Comment: Thanks . I meant , what about on TreeView ?

Comment: @zhumeng_459: Its Not done in Tree view with reason like :
- Tree/List View are not Full representation of the Model. It just kind of summary view.
- In list/tree View while row should be generic on click event of the record to open the from view.
This is not done for list/tree relation field. It certialy needs Immplmentation. and Current list view are genric implmentation.

Comment: Thank u . I think it's a import function .